# Insert in specific columns with pdo

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have two registration form for users one of them requires more fields to enter data.

My first question is about how to make tables? I think I should make one table because for loging I should connect to one table only

But in this way how should I insert data from the form which has less fields?
I wrote this code:

```
    $id='';
    $password = md5($password);
    $data = array(':id'=>$id,':password'=>$password,':mobile'=>$mobile, ':email'=>$email);
    $stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO users VALUES(:id,:password, :mobile, :email ) ');
    $stmt->execute($data);
```

and it makes an error because there are some other columns in the table like `$firstname`, `$lastname` etc. So what should I do?

One way is that I write:

```
$firstname= '';
$lastname = '';
```

in this way I insert empty data but is it the correct way?

Answer (score 2):

You should always explicitly name the columns you're working with in all operations, never simply rely on their implicit "order". For INSERT queries, the syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO users (id, password, mobile, email)
VALUES (:id, :password, :mobile, :email);
```